# Criar elementos em tempo de execução no Android

Tags: android

É possível criar elementos em tempo de execução no Android?

Por exemplo, quero construir um app onde o usuário possa criar um questionário ou um checklist e salvar no banco de dados.

Em função das questões ou dos itens a serem verificados, que foram criados pelo usuário, o aplicativo iria montando os elementos para as ações do usuário.

É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível criar elementos de interface, em tempo de execução.
Algo como:

```
//...
parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

TextView tv = new TextView(context);
parent.addView(tv);
//...
```

É algo assim que procura?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. A minha ideia se baseia em algo parecido com o joomla, onde se consegue criar elementos (comboboxes, check, radiogroup, etc) e as especificações são salvas no banco de dados, bastando o sistema ler essas informações e criar os elementos da tela para o usuário. Vou testar os códigos e volto para comentar.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível. Você pode usar o método addView() em qualquer ViewGroup como LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc. Segue um exemplo:

```
package com.example.androidview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  LinearLayout mainLayout = 
    (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

  //newButton added to the existing layout
  Button newButton = new Button(this);
  newButton.setText("Hello");
  mainLayout.addView(newButton);

  //anotherLayout and anotherButton added 
  //using addContentView()
  LinearLayout anotherLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  Button anotherButton = new Button(this);
  anotherButton.setText("I'm another button");
  anotherLayout.addView(anotherButton);

  addContentView(anotherLayout, linearLayoutParams);
 }

}
```

Mais detalhes aqui:

http://android-coding.blogspot.com.br/2013/10/add-view-programmatically-using-addview.html

Comment: Marcio, poderia adicionar uma parte do código aqui no StackOverflow? Pois vai que esse link quebra, e ao passar do tempo não teriamos a informação

Comment: Editei minha resposta

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou testar e volto para comentar.